# .env not readable on google-app-engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using `Lumen` framework which is minimal framework of `Laravel` which uses `vlucas/phpdotenv` as a dependency. Internally `phpdotenv` checks for `.env` readability using [`is_readable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) function of `PHP` which tells whether a file is readable or not. Have checked with file path which is correct and working fine on local. But on `google-app-engine` `is-readable` function is returning as **`false`**.

Below is a snapshot of code where it is checking for readability

[image: phpdotenv is_readable check snapshot]

So there can be two reasons I can think of for above **returning false** :-

1. Either file was ignored while uploading to because of it's name which can be true as on dashboard source also I am not able to see .env uploaded and it's not there in **skip_files** in `app.yaml`. Below is snapshot for same

[image: .env ignored while deployment]

2. As in most of unix systems all files starting from . are hidden so if we are going with this theory of not showing in dashboard then this file is not readable in `google-app-engine`.

In both the cases not able to figure out a way to resolve it as `google-app-engine standard environment` doesn't give any way to change file permission or to login to machine and manually create these files.

What can be solution to this as it's pretty common thing as most popular `PHP frameworks` like **laravel, lumen etc.**. and even other language frameworks also have `.env` concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having a `skip_files:` section in `app.yaml` means that you'll pick up the defaults. The defaults ignore files and directories that start with `.`. Adding your own `skip_files:` will override the default behavior.

This is described in the `skip_files` section in [the configuration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref).